# Filtering multiple times on one dictionary

Tags: filter, swift3

I currently run this code:

```
searchterm = "test"
results = resultsArray.filter { $0.description.contains (searchterm!) }
```

My question is how do I search in `company_name` or `place` or any other field in my model and add it to the results.

Do I need to use filters together and then append the results to a new variable instance of my model?

EDIT:

If "test" is in company_name, place and description. I want all three results returned. However, if "test" is only in place, I need only place to be returned.

EDIT2:

This is an example of my model return. Is this a dictionary or an array? I'm sorry I dont 100% percent know the difference. I know ' "this": is ' what a dictionary looks like, however because there were [] brackets around them, I thought that made it an array...

```
struct GraphData {

    var description: String
    var company_name: String
    var places: String

    init(description: String, company_name: String, places: String){
        self.description = description
        self.company_name = company_name
        self.places = places
    }

func toAnyObject() -> Any {
    print("return")
    return [
        "description": description,
        "company_name": company_name,
        "places": places,
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're filtering a dictionary, and not an array?

Comment: Dictionary, I believe.. lol The code above works fine

Comment: They why did you name it `resultsArray`?

Comment: I was writing the question quickly

Comment: Can you please show us a declaration of `resultsArray` so we can see what the original data actually looks like?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this would be to create a custom `contains` method in your model which can you can use to match the search term against any property in the model:

```
class YourModel {
    var company_name: String
    var description: String
    var place: String

    // ...

    func contains(_ searchTerm: String) -> Bool {
        return self.company_name.contains(searchTerm)
            || self.description.contains(searchTerm)
            || self.place.contains(searchTerm)
    }
}
```

You can then simply filter using your custom method:

```
let searchTerm = "test"    
let results = resultsArray.filter { $0.contains(searchTerm) }
```

Comment: I'll try this in a sec, it looks interesting.

Comment: I've just seen your comments on your original post. Can you clarify whether `resultsArray` is (A) an array of dictionaries or (B) an array of custom models or (C) a dictionary?

Comment: Aleks, I'm not actually sure... I'm using a model but the results are in an dictionary. Does that means its and array of a custom model?

Comment: If the code you posted works, `resultsArray` appears to be an array of custom models. What do you want the end result to be after filtering? An array of strings or a dictionary?

Comment: A dictionary... Currently whatever it is doing works perfectly except that if I search for Nike, Nike is not contained in the description, so Nike returns nil. So I need to check other areas for specific search terms, and remove duplicates as well.

Comment: Could it be a matter of case sensitivity? What if you try `localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchTerm)`?

Comment: It works, however I run into the same problem before where the first instance is true and exits the function. I think I need to use pass, or whatever its called in swift. Or a bunch of if statements. lol I think with both answers I can figure out what I need done. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Is this **resultsArray** a *dictionary* or an *array*?

You can do something like this

```
let searchTerm = "test"
let filter = resultsArray.filter{ $0.company_name!.contains(searchTerm) || $0.place!.contains(searchTerm) }
```

Edit

```
class TestClass: NSObject {

    var place: String?
    var company_name: String?

    func contain(searchTerm: String) -> [String] {

        var result = [String]()

        if let placeVal = place, placeVal.contains(searchTerm) {
            result.append(placeVal)
        }

        if let companyVal = company_name, companyVal.contains(searchTerm) {
            result.append(companyVal)
        }

        return result
    }
}

let searchTerm = "test"
let filter = resultsArray.map { $0.contain(searchTerm: searchTerm) }
```

Comment: Its a dictionary. In this example, if "test" was in both company_name and place, it would return both results or just the results in company_name? I was under the impression that when chaining filter together, it would stop after the first true statement.

Comment: yes if the $0.company_name!.contains(searchTerm) evaluated to true then ti will stop from that (because this is a OR condition )

Comment: then you can use AND (&&) but then both condition must be true. That means if you want to get any result from filter  both "$0.company_name!.contains(searchTerm)" and "$0.place!.contains(searchTerm)" must evaluate to true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138694/discussion-between-keaz-and-denis).